# I have created a custom post type. single page for that custom post showing blank page

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I have created a custom post type. Single posts for that custom post type is not working. showing white page but html are loading properly. Here is the url https://bestswiss.ch/vendorpartner/formforum

```
   ////code



 $labels = array(
            'name'               => __( 'Partner' ),
            'singular_name'      => __( 'vendorpartner' ),
            'add_new'            => __( 'Add New vendorpartner' ),
            'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New vendorpartner' ),
            'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit vendorpartner' ),
            'new_item'           => __( 'Add New vendorpartner' ),
            'view_item'          => __( 'View vendorpartner' ),
            'search_items'       => __( 'Search vendorpartner' ),
            'not_found'          => __( 'No events found' ),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No events found in trash' )
        );
        $supports = array(
            'title',
            'editor',
            'thumbnail',
            'comments',
            'revisions',
            'page-attributes'
        );
        $args = array(
            'labels'               => $labels,
            'supports'             => $supports,
            'public'               => true,
            'capability_type'      => 'post',
            'rewrite'              => array( 'slug' => 'vendorpartner' ),
            'has_archive'          => true,
            'menu_position'        => 30,
            'menu_icon'            => 'dashicons-calendar-alt',
            'register_meta_box_cb' => 'wpt_add_event_metaboxes',
        );
        register_post_type( 'vendorpartner', $args );
```

Comment: Enable your debug mode and check error
how to enable debug mode steps Go to your wordpress directory folder and find file wp-config.php open it and define( 'WP_DEBUG', false ); to define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );

Comment: Is this the whole real code? Where's the init hook instance? Does the wpt_add_event_metaboxes function exist?

Answer (score 0):

create single-vendorpartner.php and paste the following codes

```html
<?php get_header('');?>
<!--start container-->
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
    
      <?php the_title(); ?>
      
      <?php the_content(); ?>
  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php endwhile ?>
<!--end container-->
<?php get_footer() ?>
```

**change permalinks**, and see the changes.

Comment: Careful with this: save the above code as single-vendorpartner.php as vendorpartner is the real post type name.

Answer (score 0):

The important thing to be aware of here is WordPress's template hierarchy. Many views are rendered with a certain template file based on naming logic.

Single posts use a `single-` prefix. Just add the id of your custom post type and you get the file name you need to create. Create a template with this name and your single view of that CPT will use it:

```
single-vendorpartner.php
```

Interesting thing is that the hierarchy will point to the next template name up the chain if the default file name file is not there. basically `index.php` is the fallback for nearly everything and that template is likely only setup to handle your blog.

Here is the documentation: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/. Print out the chart on that page and put it up on your wall.